# Setting different CSS for all pages except home.php

Tags: theme-development, css

I'm creating my first WordPress theme and I'm new to PHP. I've done some looking around but I can't seem to find my specific answer.

In my header.php I want to include some conditional logic to set CSS for all pages except the home page. This is my current code but there must be a better way.

Couple of other things I'm wondering about... Do I need to make sure the admin doesn't pick up these styles and is my method considered a 'best practice' or is there a better way to go about this?

```
<!--The Global Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" media="screen" />
<!-- Styles specific to the home page -->
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()) :?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ot_nav_widget.css" media="screen" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/birdcage.css" media="screen" />
<?php endif;?>
 <!-- Set styles for any pages other than the home page -->
<?php if(!is_home() || !is_front_page()) :?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ot_internal_nav_widget.css" media="screen" />
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I suspect the down-vote is because this question is answered more completely elsewhere? In the spirit of helpfulness would the down-voter mind including a link to the duplicate answer for other folks that might come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php if(!is_home() || !is_front_page()) :?>
```

you could use

```
<?php else: ?>
```

This style will not affect the wp-admin part, only the front end of your web since this is used in `header.php`.

A safe way is to use `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` as described here in the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

In your case it could be:

```
function wpse85659_theme_styles()  
{ 
  // Register the styles
  wp_register_style( 'global-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '20130213', 'screen' );
  wp_register_style( 'home-widget-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ot_nav_widget.css', array('global-style'), '20130213', 'screen' );
  wp_register_style( 'home-birdcage-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/birdcage.css', array('global-style','home-widget-style'), '20130213', 'screen');
  wp_register_style( 'internal-widget-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ot_internal_nav_widget.css', array('global-style'), '20130213', 'screen' );

  // Enqueing:
  wp_enqueue_style( 'global-style' );
  if(is_home() || is_front_page()) :
    wp_enqueue_style( 'home-widget-style' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'home-birdcage-style' );
  else:
    wp_enqueue_style( 'internal-widget-style' );
  endif;

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse85659_theme_styles');
```

You can place this code example into your `functions.php` file. Just remember to use the `wp_head()` in your `header.php` for this method.

Comment: This is an extraordinarily helpful answer. Thank you for the code samples as I am a beginner in this arena. I've been a ColdFusion programmer for a while and this is all new territory for me.